# Frobenius norm optimization problem

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, svd, orthogonal-matrices, tensor-decomposition

How to solve the following optimization problem which arises in the field of Higher Order SVD?

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, $W \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times l}$.

find $\arg \max _{A}\|A^T W\|_F$ s.t. $A$ columnwise orthogonal.

$\| \cdot \|_{F}$ here represents the Frobenius norm. I know the solution is the matrix containing the left singular values of $W$, but it is not clear to me why.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I think you want argmin instead of argmax.